# Nginx custom $request_body

Tags: nginx, lua

I'm trying to get Nginx [mod_zip](https://github.com/evanmiller/mod_zip) module working with HttpSecureLink module.

whenever server gets a request with the header `X-Archive-Files: zip`, module starts reading body of the request and starts compressing and serving files on the fly.

I've set the header like this (using more_set_headers module) and it works perfectly.

```
location /a/ {
    more_set_headers 'X-Archive-Files: zip';
}
```

so whenever a request hits http://mydomain.com/a/ will set `X-Archive-Files: zip` header.

Now the **problem** is how am I going to **set the body contents**?

Example contents:

```
1034ab38 428    /data/foo.txt   Document1.txt
83e8110b 100339 /data/bar.txt   Textfile.txt
```

I'm also using HttpLuaModule, Echo, modules and none of them change the request body properly.

Tried with lua

```
content_by_lua '

  local content = { "- 0  /data/12.txt 1.txt" }
  ngx.print(content)

';
```

Everything works fine when doing this with PHP

```
<?php

header("X-Archive-Files: zip");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=Arch.zip");
echo "- 0  /data/12.txt 1.txt";

?>
```

but I don't need to do this with PHP.

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: http://tech.3scale.net/2013/01/09/augment-your-api-without-touching-it/ maybe this will help